# Extending prototype within anonymous function - strange effects

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

When experimenting with a method to make private static methods, I came across this very strange behavior. In the following code, the public method getData is overwritten by it's own return data, though it is never explicitly called! This is very strange to me and wondered what is going on here. I suppose it serves me right for not just encompassing the entire page in the anonymous function as per the module pattern, but I would still like to understand this bug.

```
function MyClass() {
    this._prop = true;
}
MyClass.prototype.getData = function () {
    this._prop = false;
    return { a: 2344, b: 765, c: 234 };
}

(function () {
    var privateStatic = 0;
    MyClass.prototype.getCount = function () {
        return privateStatic++;
    }
} ());

var m = new MyClass();
console.log(m.getData()); //Error (object is not a function)
console.log(m.getData); //prints {a:2344,b:765,c:234}
```

Comment: you need a semi (;) after the getData method assignment; it's an expression. otherwise that function is passed the result of your anon and the result of that is assigned to instance.getData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this strange behavior is that getData is being immediately invoked due to the lack of a semicolon after the function declaration (great spot, dandavis) and the IIFE straight after it, wrapped in parens. Essentially, this:

```
MyClass.prototype.getData = function () {
  this._prop = false;
  return { a: 2344, b: 765, c: 234 };
} // Notice no semicolon here!
(function () {
  var privateStatic = 0;
  MyClass.prototype.getCount = function () {
    return privateStatic++;
  }
} ());
```

Becomes this:

```
MyClass.prototype.getData = function () {
  this._prop = false;
  return { a: 2344, b: 765, c: 234 };
}();
```

Which is therefore setting the getData property to the return value of the function. Hence why `m.getData` prints out `{ a: 2344, b: 765, c: 234 }` and `m.getData()` doesn't work (it's no longer a function!).

Comment: Optional semicolons in Javascript strike again! Thanks jayrobin and  dandavis for explaining what seemed to be the darkest of black magicks.